# Oracle automated csv file imports from folder

Tags: oracle, csv, import, directory

I am Currently downloading/updating
about 4,000 csv files that contain 
Stock Data(Open/High/Low/Close/Volume)
to a single Directory **"Folder"**

the csv files are updated daily,
new data is added every morning,
and sometimes existing data is rectified.  (I am using a CsiData's Unfair Advantage, which corrects former incorrect data.)

I would like to have the **"csv files"** in the **"Folder"**
to be imported automatically into my **"Oracle Database"**,
at a designated time.

Comment: How do you intend to load 'rectified' data? Using [external tables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_concepts.htm#SUTIL011) might make that easier, but you'd have to automatically create a new table for each file, which isn't ideal. Scripting calls to `sqlldr` sounds doable though, apart from that 'rectify' issue.

Comment: You need to do scripting (either shell or cmd based on your OS) that should create a single file from all the files in the Folder and then move it to Oracle directory with a fixed file name. After that, as Alex already suggested, use external table on the new file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the folder is accessible via oracle, and you have the correct permissions to see the folder
Here's a rough guide to the code needed (not tested) see [Ask Tom](http://asktom.oracle.com)

```
CREATE TABLE files_to_process (file_name VARCHAR2(255));

CREATE OR REPLACE
AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "DirectoryList"
AS
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class DirectoryList
{
public static void ListAllFiles(String directory)
                     throws SQLException
    {
        File path = new File( directory );
        String[] list = path.list();
        String element;

        for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        {
            element = list[i];
            sql 
            { 
                INSERT INTO Files_to_process (FILENAME) VALUES (:element) 
            };
        }
    }

}
/


CREATE OR REPLACE  PROCEDURE get_files_to_process( p_directory in varchar2 )
  AS LANGUAGE JAVA
  NAME 'DirectoryList.ListAllFiles( java.lang.String )';
/

BEGIN
    delete Files_to_process;

    get_files_to_process( '\mnt\your_folder' );

    for rec in (select file_name from Files_to_process)
    LOOP
        process_file(file_name);

    END LOOP;
END;

--so the procedure below can open the files......
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY in_files as '\mnt\your_folder';

create table stock_file_to_process as
(
--your csv structure here
--STOCKID number, 
--Open number,
--High number,
--Low number,
--Close number,
--Volume number
)
  ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
  ( type oracle_loader
    default directory in_files
    access parameters
    ( fields terminated by ',' )
    location ('emp.dat')
  )
  /


CREATE PROCEDURE process_file(p_filename varchar2(255)) as
BEGIN
    execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE file_to_process LOCATION( p_filename )';

    for rec in (select Stockid,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume from stock_file_to_process)
    LOOP
        --your processing code here

    END LOOP;

END;
```